# Scrapy - making selections from dropdown(e.g.date) on webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, scrapy

I'm new to scrapy and python and i am trying to scrape data off the following start url .

After login, this is my start url--->

start_urls = ["http://www.flightstats.com/go/HistoricalFlightStatus/flightStatusByFlight.do?"]

(a) from there i need to interact with the webpage to select ---by-airport---

and then make ---airport, date, time period selection---

how can i do that? i would like to loop over all time periods and past dates..

- I have used firebug to see the source, I cannot show here as I do not have enough points to post images..
- i read a post mentioning the use of Splinter..

(b) after the selections it will lead me to a page where there are links to the eventual page with the information i want. How do i populate the links and make scrapy look into every one to extract the information?

-using rules? where should i insert the rules/ linkextractor function?

I am willing to try myself, hope help can be given to find posts that can guide me.. I am a student and I have spent more than a week on this.. I have done the scrapy tutorial, python tutorial, read the scrapy documentation and searched for previous posts in stackoverflow but I did not manage to find posts that cover this.

a million thanks.

my code so far to log-in and the items to scrape via xpath from the eventual target site:

```
`import scrapy

from tutorial.items import FlightItem
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

class flightSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "flight"
    allowed_domains = ["flightstats.com"]
    login_page =     'https://www.flightstats.com/go/Login/login_input.do;jsessionid=0DD6083A334AADE3FD6923ACB8DDCAA2.web1:8009?'
    start_urls = [
    "http://www.flightstats.com/go/HistoricalFlightStatus/flightStatusByFlight.do?"]

def init_request(self):
    #"""This function is called before crawling starts."""
    return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

def login(self, response):
 #"""Generate a login request."""
    return FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata= {'loginForm_email': 'marvxxxxxx@hotmail.com', 'password': 'xxxxxxxx'},callback=self.check_login_response)

def check_login_response(self, response):
        #"""Check the response returned by a login request to see if we aresuccessfully logged in."""
    if "Sign Out" in response.body:
        self.log("\n\n\nSuccessfully logged in. Let's start crawling!\n\n\n")
         # Now the crawling can begin..

    return self.initialized() # ****THIS LINE FIXED THE LAST PROBLEM*****

    else:
            self.log("\n\n\nFailed, Bad times :(\n\n\n")
         # Something went wrong, we couldn't log in, so nothing happens.

def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div'):
        item = flightstatsItem()
        item['flight_number'] = sel.xpath('/div[1]/div[1]/h2').extract()
        item['aircraft_make'] = sel.xpath('/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]').extract()
        item['dep_date'] = sel.xpath('/div[2]/div[1]/div').extract()
        item['dep_airport'] = sel.xpath('/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]').extract()
        item['arr_airport'] = sel.xpath('/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]').extract()
        item['dep_gate_scheduled'] = sel.xpath('/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]').extract()
        item['dep_gate_actual'] = sel.xpath('/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]').extract()
        item['dep_runway_actual'] = sel.xpath('/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]').extract()
        item['dep_terminal'] = sel.xpath('/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]').extract()
        item['dep_gate'] = sel.xpath('/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]').extract()
        item['arr_gate_scheduled'] = sel.xpath('/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]').extract()
        item['arr_gate_actual'] = sel.xpath('/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]').extract()
        item['arr_terminal'] = sel.xpath('/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]').extract()
        item['arr_gate'] = sel.xpath('/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]').extract()

        yield item`
```